# print integer value in 16bits binary - MIPS

Tags: mips

I am struggling with a question I got.
I have an integer number between `-9999 to 9999`
I need to present the number in 16bits.

for example:

- number 1 will be printed as: `0000000000000001`
- number 4 will be printed as: `0000000000000100`

and so on... (be aware that I have in the range negative numbers that need to be printed in two complements).

how can I do it?
I can not use syscall 35, I need to print it with a loop.

Comment: As programmers, the way we solve problems is to simplify what we don't yet understand into smaller, more manageable pieces.  Here from a top level perspective, you need two things. (1) an algorithm, and (2) an assembly version of it.  Any language can do the algorithm, as it is basic mathematics, so work it out in a language you know.  Then your assembly question will be how to I write this same for loop in assembly or how do I divide in assembly.  Disconnecting the algorithm development from the assembly translation allows searching from wider sources.

Answer (score 2):

Well it took me a while but I solved it.
the int is in $t0

here is the code part:

```
li $t1,15 #set 15 for the loops to print 16 bits
li $v0,1 #print integer

bgtz $t0,positive_loop#for positive values

positive_loop:
    srlv $t3, $t0, $t1 
    andi $t4, $t3, 1 # mask the rightmost bit
    move $a0,$t4
    syscall
    addi $t1, $t1, -1 # decrement the loop counter
        bne $t1,-1, positive_loop # repeat until the loop counter is -1
```

Comment: I was just about to suggest this exact method funnily enough.